Jquery snowfall plugin is adjusting the page height
I am using this snowfall plugin on my demo site:
https://github.com/loktar00/JQuery-Snowfall
My problem is, that on my homepage, the plugin is adjusting the page height, and i can only use the vertical scrollbar very hard. On mobile, its okay, the problem is on pc.
You can take a look at the site here:
Click here to check demo
I call the plugin with this, nothing extra:
$(document).ready(function(e) {$("body").snowfall({image :"../images/assets/flake.png", minSize: 5, maxSize:25, flakeCount:20, maxSpeed:2  });});

What do you guys think, whats going on with this ?
